# Set UIContainer View Height According to table

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

Can I adjust the height of container view (or UIContainer) according to size of the tableview inside the view controller for storyboards?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could first add a constraint for the height of the tableView.

Then simply add a constraint 'Equal Heights' between the tableView and the containerView.

You'll then have to change the 'multiplier' value of the constraint according to what you want exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a question when I set height of tableview in one storyboard file, can I still set the height of UIContainer equal to height of tableview in another storyboard file. Can I do this programmatically?

Comment: Hi...Can anyone help me on this?